# Working with a slow connection

Tags: ftp, textmate, synchronization

I'm working with Textmate and Transmit.

I work locally and sync with the server every now and then.

At the moment I'm doing this by myself, it's slow and takes some time.

What are the best ways to sync between servers?

Also, is it possible to archive the directory and unpack it at the server? This would be so much faster...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> What are the best ways to sync between
>   servers?

[`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/rsync/)? It's pretty much designed to do that exact task (syncing changes between files) and comes standard on most *nix OSes (including Mac OS X).

Comment: Historically, rsync with HFS+ has been quite buggy, with regards to OS X extended attributes, resource forks etc. (*including* Apple's patched version), and I've found Unison sync - http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/ a more reliable alternative. I've not tried rsync for a while, it may have improved.

Answer (score 0):

If you have, or could obtain, ssh access you could use something like [SSHFS](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS) with [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/)

This would let you remote mount the server filesystem though Finder, as if it were local, but only using a [ssh secure shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) remote login.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

```
rsync --help
```

**Option 2**

Get an editor which is able to work with remote files.

**Option 3**

Mount remote directory and use your favorite editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Yummy FTP](http://www.yummysoftware.com/) is for Mac and much faster than Transmit. It's the best you can get if you have only a FTP connection.